# Is my sound card dead? Ubuntu/Xubuntu no audio

Tags: sound, xubuntu, hardware, libraries

I was wondering if anyone knew how I can check to see if my sound card is no longer functional or if I'm missing some libraries or something. The sound was working fine for a while and then it just died all of a sudden ... rebooting my system doesn't help. Is there output from any command that you'd like to see that might help with answering my question? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There could be so many reasons behind this that the best advice for you is to follow a sound troubleshooting guide like [this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure). Whenever I have problems I use it. It has saved me many times!